# Updating or create new collection in node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two collections Order and TabItems.
I'm getting array of order ids and I need to loop those id's and check record is present in TabItem. If record exists then update the TabItem else create new TabItem. Below is my code:

```
async.each(orders, function(order, done){
    TabItem.findOne({order_id: order._id}, function(err, tab){
       if(err) { console.log(err)}
       if(tab != null) {
         tab.quantity += order.quantity
         tab.save(function(err){
          if(err) { throw err }
          done(true)
         })
       }
       else {
            TabItem.create({order_id: data._id, menu_item_id: each_tab.menu_item_id, quantity: each_tab.quantity}, function(err, tab_item){
                if(err){

                }
            })
        }

    })
    done();
})
```

Server is hanging when I'm trying to call this method. Can anyone help me out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
async.each(orders, function(order, done){

    TabItem.update({order_id: order._id,menu_item_id:order.menu_item_id},{$inc:{quantity:order.quantity},{upsert:true}}).exec(function(err,result){
      if(!err) {
        console.log('item updated successfully');
         done();
      } else {
        done(true);
      }
    });       
});
```

Hope this Helps You.

Comment: Thanks for help. What about create if record not present.

Comment: see `{upsert:true}`. If record not exists with specified fields , it would insert record itself.